# iOS 5 UISplitViewController not calling ShouldHideViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using MonoDevelop 3.0.3 and Monotouch 5.2.12

Why is "ShouldHideViewController" in a "UISplitViewController" class never called in iOS 5.1?

If I don't assign "ShouldHideViewController" and the "will show/hide" properties, the left/main view is displayed correctly but then I have no way of hiding/showing the "BarButtonItem" in my main view (viewFees).

Following is my code for the split view class:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace PlazaTimePad 
{
  public class FeesSplitViewController : UISplitViewController
  {
    CalendarMonthViewController viewCalendar;
    FeeListViewController viewFees;

    public FeesSplitViewController () : base()
    {
      this.TabBarItem.Title = "My Time"; 
      viewFees = new FeeListViewController ();
      viewCalendar = new CalendarMonthViewController (viewFees);

      ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {viewCalendar, viewFees};

      WillHideViewController += (object sender, UISplitViewHideEventArgs e) => {
        viewFees.AddContentsButton (e.BarButtonItem);
      };

      WillShowViewController += (object sender, UISplitViewShowEventArgs e) => {
        viewFees.RemoveContentsButton ();
      };

      ShouldHideViewController += (svc, viewController, inOrientation) => {
        return inOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || 
               inOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The work around was to create my own Delegate by sub classing UISplitViewControllerDelegate. In this sub class I overwrote WIllHideViewController and WillShowViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just override `WillRotate` or `DidRotate` for what you are trying to do.

Here is are links:

http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.WillRotate(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation%2CSystem.Double)

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.DidRotate(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation)

If you browse those documents with the native help browser (Help menu -> Help), you will get the full Apple documentation integrated with C#.

Comment: How do I get/reference the BarButtonItem passed as an argument to WillHideViewController?